# Cylinder parameters: elements or attributes

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the [cylinder SDF specification](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=geometry#geometry_cylinder), the radius and length of a cylinder are children elements, as the example in that website shows:

```
<cylinder>
    <radius>1</radius>
    <length>1.2</length>
 </cylinder>
```

However, in Gazebo5 this throws the error:

`[ERROR] [1457697849.467197389]: Cylinder shape must have both length and radius attributes`

Therefore, it looks like Gazebo 5 requires those values as attributes:

```
<geometry>
    <cylinder length="1.2" radius="1"/>
</geometry>
```

And this works OK. Which one is correct? Is it a Gazebo bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12831/cylinder-parameters:-elements-or-attributes/) by [Javi V](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1327/javi-v/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 57 on 2016-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This error doesn't seem to be coming from Gazebo, Gazebo's errors start with `[Err]`.

Are you sure you're not using URDF instead of SDF? In [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Adding%20Physical%20and%20Collision%20Properties%20to%20a%20URDF%20Model), radius and length would be attributes.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javi V](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1327/javi-v/) on 2016-03-14**:
Oops you are right! I am using URDF.